# How can i resolve the path laocation in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a test.exe file in location C:\pathfinder\test.exe . I am able execute it using

```
C:\\demo\test.exe
```

in  batch file.

But if the same file i try to execute in location

```
C:\Users\Anuj\test.exe
```

Its throwing an error "The system cannot find the path specified."

Comment: Makes no sense. Calling `"C:\Users\Anuj\test.exe"` would do fine. Are you sure on correct paths and files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the exe file is in the same dir:

```
pushd %~dp0
test.exe
```